# Batch update table row, reorder & update at the same time?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

## Description

I have a CoreData entry called Person, I fetch it using NSFetchedResultsController, with a fetchRequest ordered by property "name". Then I display the "name" in the table view cell.

## Problem

When I change the entity's "name" property and the rows reorder, `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` does give me a `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.move`. But the "name" displayed on the cell is outdated, meaning I'm not receiving `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update`

The [Table View Programming Guide: Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) says batch updates do updates first, then deletions, lastly insertions.

> It defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled the deletions of rows or sections. The table view behaves the same way with reloading methods called inside an update block—the reload takes place with respect to the indexes of rows and sections before the animation block is executed. This behavior happens regardless of the ordering of the insertion, deletion, and reloading method calls.

## Question

Any idea on how the notifications sent by `NSFetchedResultsController` are implemented, specifically on the ordering of insert, delete, update & move?

Or how can I use some kind of code to efficiently (meaning partial update, not reload all data) solve this particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is non-standard. The `sectionNameKeyPath` is really meant for **sections** not **rows**. Fetch the `Person` entity and populate the cell with a person's name directly via `itemForRowAtIndexPath`.

You will then have the expected change types available.

Comment: My bad. I actually mean the fetch request sort descriptor. The question is updated.

Setting `sectionNameKeyPath` is just shouldn't conflict with your fetch request ordering. And even if I don't divide the objects into sections, the problem is still there.

Comment: So what is the problem? You now have `.move` as an option in the delegate callback for the rows, right?